# predict the probability of buying a product

Tags: machine-learning, r, predictive-modeling, regression, categorical-data

I have a huge dataset with 3 variables `Company_ID, Area_code, Product_ID` each one of them is a categorical variable of levels `1500,50,15` respectively,where `Product_ID` is the product the `Company_ID` is using.Each company can be located in more than one `area_code` and can be using more than one product.Lets call this train data.

Given a combination of `Company_ID, Area_code, Product_ID` ,
`example- comp_025, area_012, p_10` that is not present in train data,i have to predict the probability that a company `Company_ID` located in area `Area_Code` uses the product `Product_ID`. So that i can recommend that product to company.

I am a beginner and having difficulty in coming up with a model. Any input is highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like Naive Bayes of `e1071` package could help.

Given the model `product_id ~ comp_id + area_id` it will construct conditional probabilities that may reveal some pattern in your data. For specifics, however, some sample data is nescessary.